# How to webscrape the table data(includes merged cells) which have same class names using python and selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

From the image,

2002 and  December and  1,262.516  -->> In html tag, 2002 as td[1] and December as td[2] and 1,262.516 as td[3]

Immediate next row , assume 2002 Q4 as td [1]   4,017.422 td[2]

so that how can I store 4,017.422 in domesitc ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/45F3v.png

If anyone knows comment your email id please.

Here the link to refer : https://www.transtats.bts.gov/freight.asp

Comment: can u share html ?

Comment: can ur share your mail id?

Comment: amitjain.coer191@gmail.com

Comment: //tr/td[text()='2002 Q4']//following-sibling::td[1]

Comment: for one this is possible in that table there are many merged data like these so that wat to do?

Comment: Please post Your relevant HTML?Screenshot not helped you to get better resolution.

Comment: can u share your email id @KunduK ?

Comment: @MonikRaj : Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import Following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

To get all elements try below code. `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following xpath

```
allelements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@class='dataTD' and @colspan='2']/following::td[1]")))
for item in allelements:
    print(item.text)
```

OR use following css selector.

```
allelements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td.dataTD[colspan='2']+td")))
for item in allelements:
    print(item.text)
```

** Expected Output**:

```
  Year        Month         Domestic

2003         December        1,424.216

2003Total       -           15,232.525

%Chg over 2002  -
Q4 Only                       5.13% 

2004        January         1,234.820
```

---

**EDITED**
Based on your expected output.Here is the updated code.
Create one function and pass the string value.

```
def Get_details(strtext):
  Year=[]
  Month=[]
  Domestic=[]
  allelements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td.dataTD")))
  for element in allelements:
     if element.text==strtext and element.get_attribute("colspan")=='2':
         Year.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]").text)
         Month.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[2]").text)
         Domestic.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[3]").text)
         Year.append(element.text)
         Month.append("-")
         Domestic.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./following::td[1]").text)
         if element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]").get_attribute("colspan")=='2':
             Year.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]").text)
             Month.append("-")
             Domestic.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[2]").text)
             Year.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[2]/td[1]").text)
             Month.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[2]/td[2]").text)
             Domestic.append(element.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[2]/td[3]").text)


  print(Year)
  print(Month)
  print(Domestic)
```

If you call the function with `2003 Total`

```
Get_details("2003 Total")
```

**Output**:

```
['2003', '2003 Total', '%Chg over 2002\nQ4 Only', '2004']
['December', '-', '-', 'January']
['1,424.216', '15,232.525', '5.13%', '1,234.820']
```

If you call the function with `2004 Total`

```
Get_details("2004 Total")
```

**Output**:

```
['2004', '2004 Total', '%Chg over 2003', '2005']
['December', '-', '-', 'January']
['1,526.984', '16,452.807', '8.01%', '1,280.516']
```

Comment: `year= [ 2003, 2003total,%Chg over 2002 Q4 Only,2004]
        Month =[ December,  , , January]
        Domestic= [1,424, 15,232,5.13,1234 ]`

Comment: @MonikRaj : Updated the answer.